# populate tableview with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview

Only recently I decided to move to javafx, this is part of my first try with it.
I do not understand why the tableview is not populated.

The `System.out.println(" results ? " + row[col]);` outputs the right content.

```
TableColumn<Table1, Integer> itemIdCol = new TableColumn<>("Id");
itemIdCol.setMinWidth(100);        

TableColumn<Table1, String> NomeCol = new TableColumn<>("Nome");
NomeCol.setMinWidth(100);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

String sQuery = "select * from Table1";
Query hQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sQuery);
List result = hQuery.list();
Iterator iterator = result.iterator();

itemIdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table1, Integer>("itemId"));
NomeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table1, String>("itemNome"));        
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Object[] row = (Object[])iterator.next();
      for (int col = 0; col < row.length; col++) {
          System.out.println("lista i risultati ??" + row[col]);
      }
 }

table1.getItems().setAll(FXCollections.observableList(hQuery.list()));
table1.getColumns().addAll(itemIdCol, NomeCol);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

Tab tabA = new Tab();
tabA.setText("Tab A");
tabA.setContent(table1);
tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);
```

Thanks 
Alb

Comment: Post your `Table1` class.

Comment: Hi James, I actually found out what was wrong, I forgot this line of code:    data  =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();  and also missing to iterate through  Table1 obj = (Table1)iterator.next(); data.add(obj); Now data appear on the table. Thanks anyway